# Pre-compile all Handlebars templates with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I have a bunch of templates in `app/assets/handlebars` and I would like to access these templates with `Handlebars.templates.foo(context)`

So I currently have this in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.handlebars$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'handlebars-loader',
      options: {
        helperDirs: [path.join(__dirname, 'app/assets/handlebars/helpers')]
      }
    }]
  },
```

And I have this in my `app.js`

```
import Handlebars from 'handlebars/runtime'

import foo from './foo.handlebars'
import bar from './bar.handlebars'

Handlebars.templates = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
}
```

I would like to avoid this boilerplate code in `app.js` and automatically tell `webpack` to glob around `app/assets/handlebars/*.handlebars` and put all templates in `Handlebars.templates`.

I have tried some plugins, but it does not seem they do what I want. What would be the best solution?